# Garbage collection -- two cases about linkedlist

Tags: java, garbage-collection, linked-list

Case 1:
If there is a LinkedList like this:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
```

if I make `A.next = null`, so the graph would be `A --> null`  and  `B --> C --> D`

Will node `B,C,D` be garbage collected?

Case 2:
If there is a LinkedList like this:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
```

if I make `A.next = A.next.next`, so the graph would be `A --> C --> D` but also B still points to C like this: `B --> C` Will node `B` be garbage collected?

Comment: Simply make `B.next=null`

Comment: GC will clean those of memory you mentioned! since it is not on your logic of collecting instance, any instance you have created can be referenced by GC, while detecting `unreachable` by program, it will clean them!

Comment: @ling.s if i do not do this operation, node B will not be garbage collected, even though I cannot visit node B, if I traverse the whole list from root A?

Comment: Who "points to" (or references) B? If *nobody* does then B is *trivially* non-reachable. B might not be strongly reachable in any case, but if it's not trivially reachable that's the end of the story. See [Reachability of an object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reachability_of_an_object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**

```
Case 1: If there is a LinkedList like this:

A --> B --> C --> D
if I make A.next = null, so the graph would be A --> null and B --> C --> D

Will node B,C,D be garbage collected?
```

In this case B,C,D is garbage colleced if there is no reference exists for B. If you have any object that is refering to B then all three exists and treated as indepedent linked list

**Case 2**

```
Case 2: If there is a LinkedList like this:

A --> B --> C --> D
if I make A.next = A.next.next, so the graph would be A --> C --> D but also B still points to C like this: B --> C Will node B be garbage collected?
```

the same concept applies over here if any reference is there then again B->C is treatd as indepedent linked list